# Trying to network Logitech Revue (GoogleTV) and Acer Revo (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, crossover-cable, google-tv

I have a Logitech Revue (GoogleTV) and an Acer Revo (Windows 7) sitting next to each other.

I want the Revue to be able to stream video from the Revo over ethernet (via Plex and ViMu).

Both devices are getting their internet over Wifi, and I've attached their eth ports to each other with a crossover cable.

What's the best way to set up the networking on the Revo so that the Revue can see it?
With manual IP addresses on both? Or ICS on the Revo? Do I bridge the networks?

Right now I tried manual IPs, but the ethernet now shows up as a 'Public' network, and I don't know how to change it.

Comment: This can work, provided you can modify the Revue's routing table. Do you have any sort of access to it, via telnet or ssh? Alternatively, does its gui show anything like Advanced routing?

Comment: I don't know any way to modify the routing table. All it has is the standard manual IP setup.